# intelliJ scala cannot resolve reference info with such signature

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am quite sure that the `log.info(s" a $abc")` is a correct syntax for Scala, but in the IntelliJ, for the following code:

```
val abc = 1
log.info("a")
log.info(s"a $abc")
```

I receive following errors:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I suspect that the Scala version not configured correctly.

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots. It'll make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: The code seems correct. Did you try to compile and run it? 
Intellij errors are sometimes because it doesn't recognize the library correctly, in this case if you compile/run the code then you get the real error if any.

Comment: can you post the type of log and signature of log.info function?

Comment: Is it SBT project? If so, please attach build.sbt as well